# Is kdtree used for speeding k-means clustering or not?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means, kdtree

I am doing a project by using k-means and my professor suggested kdtree. I found this implementation of kdtree in python (i know that there is also in scipy, but i couldn't find any sample implementation). My question is the same as the tittle, is it used kdtree for speeding up k-means, or i am wrong?

```
data = [(2,2),(1,0),(2,3),(10,5),(59,8),(4,2)]

tree = KDTree.construct_from_data(data)
nearest = tree.query(query_point=(5,4), t=3)
print nearest
```

output:

```
[(4, 2), (2, 3), (2, 2)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As ["Making k-means even faster", p 137,](http://www.siam.org/proceedings/datamining/2010/dm10_012_hamerlyg.pdf) paper shows, kd-tree *can* be used for k means algorithm speed up for low-dimensional data, while straightforward Lloyd's algorithm is more efficient for higher dimension.

> With high-dimensional data, indexing schemes such as k-d tree do not work well

See explanations in paper.

I suggest you to use one of established k-means implementation and worry about speed improvement only if you run into severe issues. For example, afaik, sklearn's [KMeans](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) is based on Lloyd's original algorithm.

Comment: The thing is that i have to make an implementation of k-means by using kdtree. I appreciate you answer thought i cannot up-vote it (because of sufficient points) lolz

Answer (score 3):

It *can* be used, but it's nontrivial. Most people only implement the straightforward un-accelerated solution.

The problem is that most kd-tree implementations only support nearest-neighbor queries.

This only pays off if you have a **large number of clusters `k`**, and build the index on the clusters.

For full kd-tree-k-means acceleration, you would need to implement a **bipartite NN-join**, where you would both have an index on the points and on the cluster centers. I'm not aware of any kd-tree implementation that would support this.

Comment: I also have another question, by using Weka KDtree could i use the distance from it to assign a point to a cluster?

Comment: I have never used the Weka KDTree. Whether you can do this depends on *what* you store in the tree. Don't store the points; you need to store the cluster centers. If your k is small, it won't pay off.

Comment: So i need to store the centers and find the point which is the closest or?

Comment: That is the simplest approach; but it *really really really* only pays off if you have a large `k`, say 1000. For a better approach, you need to perform a 1NN join of **two** kd-trees, one containing the points and one containing the centers.

Comment: Well i have 1000 rows(documents) with 128 vector.

Comment: For discrete data (word vectors) k-means isn't too good. It minimizes variance, but variance isn't too meaningful on this data. You may want to look for better algorithms first.